# Solve hibernate error: Repeated column in mapping for entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have the table ctl with two relation to tables: psr and psg. 
This tables have the same name for the PK: COD_FILEFE_S

```
public class Psr{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "COD_FILEFE_S")
  private BigDecimal codFilefeS;
}

public class Psg{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "COD_FILEFE_S")
  private BigDecimal codFilefeS;
}
```

Its possible to map this with hibernate ?
With the following model i have the org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:

```
public class Ctl{

/** The cod filefe s. */
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Psg.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_FILEFE_S", referencedColumnName = "COD_FILEFE_S", nullable = false)
private BigDecimal codFilefeS;

/** The cod filefe s. */
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Psr.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_FILEFE_S", referencedColumnName = "COD_FILEFE_S", nullable = false)
private BigDecimal codFilefeSPert;

}
```

Comment: Format your code properly. It is unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned same name for two columns you are getting this error..
change the column name for second one..

```
public class ctl{

/** The cod filefe s. */
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Psg.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_FILEFE_S", referencedColumnName = "COD_FILEFE_S", nullable = false)
private BigDecimal codFilefeS;

/** The cod filefe s. */
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Psr.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_FILEFE_S_PERT", referencedColumnName = "COD_FILEFE_S", nullable = false)
private BigDecimal codFilefeSPert;

}
```

Comment: Yes, its the easy solution, but its imposible with the same name?

Comment: yes, definitely not possible.. how can you have two columns with same name in one table??

Comment: its two different tables psg and psr, look at targetEntity

Comment: I agree, two targetEntities are different. But you are mapping those two columns in this class.. so here internally this will create another table with two columns with the reference of two targetEntity tables..